# Pyspark operations on text, counting words, unique words, most common words

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I basically have a text, which is Moby Dick. I converted it into RDD and it looks like this:

```
['The Project Gutenberg EBook of Moby Dick; or The Whale, by Herman',
 'Melville',
 'This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with almost',
```

I have to count all words, count unique words, find 10 most common words and count how often word "whale" appears in a whole. For the task, I have to split each phrase into separate words and remove blank lines:

```
MD = rawMD.filter(lambda x: x != "")
```

For counting all the words:

```
MDcount = MD.map(lambda x: x.split(" ")).flatMap(lambda x: x).filter(lambda x: x != "")
MDcount.count()
```

And the result is: 214376, which i think is not good but anyway.

Then, for the unique words:

```
MDcount.distinct().count()
```

Result: 33282. And there is a problem, I don't know how to delete "'s" from words like "Whale's"

I tried this one instead:

```
DFcount = DFcount.select("Word", regexp_replace(col("Word"), "[_\"\'():;,.!?\\-]", "").alias("Clear"))
DFcount = DFcount.drop("Word")
DFcount.distinct().count()
```

Result: 23187 words

But still, not good enough. Wikipedia says that Moby Dick has approximately 16000 unique words.

For the most common words:

```
Word_count = DFcount.groupby('Clear').count()
Word_count.orderBy(desc('count')).show(10)
```

With te result:

```
+-----+-----+
|Clear|count|
+-----+-----+
|  the|13838|
|   of| 6654|
|  and| 6040|
|   to| 4582|
|    a| 4543|
|   in| 3950|
| that| 2857|
|  his| 2459|
|   it| 2060|
|    I| 1834|
+-----+-----+
```

And for the count of "whale"

```
RDDcount = DFcount.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])
MDwh = RDDcount.filter(lambda x: "whale" in x)
print(MDwh.count())
```

Result: 1329. Wikipedia says it's 1,685

I think something is wrong because I keep seeing apostrophes, commas, etc in the text. I think the problem exists when splitting sentences and removing unnecessary characters from them. Does anyone see the correct answer for these tasks?

Comment: why do you use RDD and not dataframe ?

Comment: Is there a big difference? I can use both

Comment: functions are not the same.

Comment: Yes, I know. I can use df instead, but I still don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've downloaded the book from the Gutenberg Project: [Moby Dick; Or, The Whale by Herman Melville](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701) in Plain Text UTF-8.

> Delete the obvious additional text from top and bottom and save it to a file: `mobydick`.

There's a function `spark.read.text` which reads a text file and creates a new row for each line. The idea is to split rows, explode them and group them by words, after that just perform needed calculations.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.text("mobydick")
df = df.filter(F.col("value") != "")  # Remove empty rows

word_counts = (
    df.withColumn("word", F.explode(F.split(F.col("value"), "\s+")))
    .withColumn("word", F.regexp_replace("word", "[^\w]", ""))
    .groupBy("word")
    .count()
    .sort("count", ascending=False)
)

# Top 10
word_counts.show(10)

# All words count
word_counts.agg(F.sum("count").alias("count_all_words")).show()

# Whale count
word_counts.filter(F.col("word").rlike("(?i)whale")).agg(
    F.sum("count").alias("whale_count")
).show()

# Unique count
print("Unique words: ", word_counts.count())
```

Result:

```
+----+-----+                                                                    
|word|count|
+----+-----+
|the |13701|
|of  |6551 |
|and |5992 |
|to  |4513 |
|a   |4491 |
|in  |3905 |
|that|2865 |
|his |2462 |
|it  |2089 |
|I   |1942 |
+----+-----+

+---------------+
|count_all_words|
+---------------+
|212469         |
+---------------+

+-----------+
|whale_count|
+-----------+
|1687       |
+-----------+

Unique words:  21837
```

With more cleaning you can get the exact results. I guess the unique words are a bit off since they require more cleaning and maybe stemming.